# Docker has is up however can't reach localhost at port 8000

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nginx

So i am trying to setup my application.

i run the command `sudo docker-compose ps` i get the following output

[image]

It looks as if everything is up and running however if i go to localhost at port 8000 i get the following screen:

[image]

I am using `nginx` and here is my configuration:

```
    # Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Note if i go to localhost (without portnumber) it shows me that my nginx has been installed correctly (the default nginx screen)

Can anyone tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Have you tried accessing via: http://127.0.0.1:8080  Also, it doesn't look like port 8000 is mapped to a host port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the port from the host to the running container.

docker run -d -p 5801:5801 -p 5802:5802 .....

Also if your workstation/laptop has more than one network card, make sure you map it to the correct one that you are trying to access it from:

```
docker run -d -p <interface IP>:<outside port>:<inside port> .....
```

See this article for more info:
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-expose-port-on-running-container/3252/5